# Является ли оборот уточняющим?

Tags: пунктуация

На сегодняшний день (,) в сложившихся экономических условиях (,) наличие альтернативных импортным материалам отечественных покрытий наиболее предпочтительно со всех точек зрения.

Answer (score 2):

Это *можно* трактовать как уточняющий оборот: сегодняшний день - тот, на который сложились новые экономические условия. Тогда нужны запятые. Но проще логически объединить время и привязанные к нему "условия" (тогда без запятых):

```
В сложившихся на сегодняшний день экономических условиях...
```

Answer (score 1):

На сегодняшний день, в сложившихся экономических условиях, наличие альтернативных импортным материалам отечественных покрытий наиболее предпочтительно со всех точек зрения.

Оборот надо обособить со значением уточнения и логического выделения, да и структура предложения такова, что оно не читается без интонационного обособления. Или надо его корректировать, как здесь уже было предложено.

Answer (score 1):

> ...наличие альтернативных импортным материал**ам** отечественных покрытий
>   наиболее предпочтительно со всех точек зрения.

*...наличие альтернативных импортным материалам отечественных покрытий...* (?)

Лучше, по-моему, так:

*...использование (вместо импортных) отечественных материалов для покрытий  предпочтительно со всех точек зрения.*

Comment: Я бы слово "наиболее" убрал: выбор всего из двух вариантов, импортное или отечественное - что предпочесть.

Comment: Наверное, Вы правы. Уберу.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, обособлять не нужно. Здесь нет уточнения как такового.